# Prove or give a counterexample: For all $x > 0$, $x^2 + 1 < (x+1)^2 \le 2(x^2 + 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am working on the following problem from Lay's Analysis with an Introduction to Proof:

> Prove or give a counter example: For all $x > 0$ we have $x^2 + 1 < (x+1)^2 \le 2(x^2 + 1)$

Now, plugging in some small values of $x$, and some large ones, it seems that the equality holds.

I am a little bit confused about how this can be proved. Clearly, $x^2 + 1 < 2(x^2 + 1)$ for positive $x$. But where does the $(x+1)^2$ come in. I feel like I am missing the big picture. Would an inductive proof be appropriate? What strategies should I be using when given a question like this?

Edit: Would $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x +1 \ge x^2 + 1, x > 0$ help?

Comment: If you expand each of the expressions in the equality some of the arguments may become clearer.

Comment: Sorry, sign was backwards - it has been fixed.

Comment: Often useful strategy: To show $f(x)\lt g(x)$, calculate $g(x)-f(x)$, show it is positive. That will work nicely here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that

$$x^2 + 1 < (x + 1)^2 \leq 2(x^2 + 1) \hspace{0.5in}\forall x > 0.$$

Since $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$, we obtain the inequality on the left from $x > 0$, as follows:

$$x > 0 \Longrightarrow 2x > 0$$

Adding $x^2 + 1$ to both sides of the inequality $0 < 2x$ gives:

$$x^2 + 1 < x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x + 1)^2.$$

For the inequality on the right, start with:

$$0 \leq (x - 1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1.$$

Adding $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ to both sides of the last inequality, we get:

$$(x + 1)^2 \leq 2x^2 + 2 = 2(x^2 + 1),$$

as desired.

Answer (score 4):

$x^2-2x+1\geq0\Rightarrow x^2+1\geq 2x$

This should solve the case...

Answer (score 2):

A symmetrical approach:

$$\begin{align}x^2+2x+1\quad &=(x+1)^2&&=2(x^2+1)-(x^2+1-2x)\\ \\
x^2+1+\underbrace{2x}_{>0}\quad &=(x+1)^2&&=2(x^2+1)-\underbrace{(x-1)^2}_{\geq 0}\\
x^2+1\quad &<(x+1)^2&&\leq 2(x^2+1)\qquad \text{QED} \blacksquare \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $ \leq (x+1)^2 = (x^2 + 1) + 2x \geq (x^2+1) $. For the other inequality we have

> $$ 2x^2+2 = (x^2+2x+1)+(x^2-2x +1 )= (x+1)^2 + (x-1)^2 \geq (x+1)^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to expand $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$. Let's look at one inequality at a time.

The first inequality is $x^2+1<(x+1)^2$. Rearranging this we get
\begin{align*}
x^2+1&<(x+1)^2 \\
\iff x^2+1&<x^2+2x+1 \\
\iff x^2+1-(x^2+1)&<x^2+2x+1-(x^2+1) \\
\iff 0&< 2x.
\end{align*}

Since $x>0$, $2x>0$ as well, proving the first inequality.

The second inequality in the chain is $(x+1)^2\leq 2(x^2+1)$. This is a similar idea:

\begin{align*}
(x+1)^2&\leq 2(x^2+1) \\
\iff x^2+2x+1 &\leq 2x^2+2 \\
\iff 2x^2+2-(x^2+2x+1) &\geq 0 \\
\iff x^2-2x+1 &\geq 0.
\end{align*}

How do we prove this final inequality? We have to factorize it. Note that $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$, so this second inequality is equivalent to

$$(x-1)^2\geq0.$$

And of course, the square of a real number is always nonnegative, so this proves the second inequality. Now the entire chain

$$x^2+1<(x+1)^2\leq2(x^2+1)$$

is proven for all $x>0$.